# Find specified text to change in project with PhpStorm

Tags: ubuntu, replace, grep, find, phpstorm

I want to change HTTP links to HTTPS in project if it is available. I have to find links with HTTP and check them if HTTPS exists I want to change HTTP with HTTPS. I`m using PhpStorm in Ubuntu.

I used <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> (Find in Path) but it shows only 99 items. My search list is getting crowded with checked unchangeable HTTP. Therefore, I cannot reach those necessary http links that have to be changed.

I tried to use grep command but I could not find how to list properly.

Comment: "I used ctrl + shift + f but it shows only 99 item. My search list is getting crowded with checked unchangeable HTTP."

Could you please clarify this, it's unclear what do you mean here. In PhpStorm try opening "Open inf Find window" to get a full list of your search results, see https://i.gyazo.com/613c9b4c480c36d181698449105f1ab9.png

Comment: You can click on the filter icon and check the: "Except Comments" maybe that will help to reduce some irrelevant

Comment: You can try throgh the terminal-->  find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/http/https/g' {} \;

Comment: I didn`t noticed the open in find window thanks. The find in path won`t show more than 100 items in the list. I used grep command in terminal but find window is better I think. I would like to change all http links with https with command but I`m not allowed to do because some http links cannot be converted into https. I`m looking for script to check http links for https if it is available then convert.